Бот на Telebot , при использовании бота одновременно двумя пользователями и более данные перемешиваются и неверно записываются в БД
Суть такая , бот для бара , при бронировании столов от двух пользователей одновременно данные первого уходят в бронь второго и наоборот . Как исправить проблему ?
import telebot
import sqlite3
import re
import datetime
import os
import requests
import time

from telebot import types

def dbconnect() :
    global db , cursor
    db = sqlite3.connect('data_base.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = db.cursor()

def tabledbconnect() :
    global tbd , tbdcursor
    tbd = sqlite3.connect('table_base.db', check_same_thread=False)
    tbdcursor = tbd.cursor()

def db_add(user_id : int , user_name : str) :
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (username, user_id , admin , phone_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' , (user_name , user_id , 0 , 0))
    db.commit()

def update_table_info(id) :
    tables.clear()
    data = tbdcursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Tables WHERE table_id = ?' , (id,)).fetchone()
    for res in data :
        tables.append(res)

def update_info(id) :
    user.clear()
    data = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_id = ?' , (id,)).fetchone()
    for res in data :
        user.append(res)

bot = telebot.TeleBot('PRIVATE_TOKEN')
admin_id = PRIVARE_ID
user = []
tables = []
global check
check = 0
global text_spam
text_spam = ""
global table_id
global buffer_table
buffer_table = 0
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
table = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Забронировать стол" , callback_data = 'table')
help = types.InlineKeyboardButton("️Помощь" , callback_data = 'help')
profile = types.InlineKeyboardButton("‍Профиль" , callback_data= 'profile')
markup.add(table , help , profile)

table_image_path = r'tables_photo.jpg'
spam_image_path = r'spam_photo.jpg'

admin_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
admin_del_reserv = types.InlineKeyboardButton("️Удалить бронь" , callback_data='admin_del_reserv')
admin_check_reserv = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Активные брони" , callback_data='admin_check_reserv')
admin_back = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Назад" , callback_data='admin_back')
admin_update_tables_photo = types.InlineKeyboardButton("️Обновить фото столов" , callback_data='admin_update_tables_photo')
admin_start_spam = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Запустить рассылку" , callback_data='admin_start_spam')
admin_edit_spam = types.InlineKeyboardButton("✏️Изменить текст и картинку рассылки" , callback_data='admin_edit_spam')
admin_markup.add(admin_del_reserv , admin_check_reserv , admin_update_tables_photo , admin_edit_spam , admin_start_spam)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message) :
    global buffer_table, table_reserv
    dbconnect()
    tabledbconnect()

    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
        user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        username TEXT NOT NULL,
        admin INTEGER NULL,
        phone_number VARCHAR(50) NULL
        )
    ''')
    db.commit()

    tbdcursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tables (
        table_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        reservation INTEGER NULL,
        phone_number VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        name TEXT NULL,
        user_id INTEGER NULL,
        time VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        persons INTEGER NULL,
        min_persons INTEGER NULL,
        max_persons INTEGER NULL
    )
    ''')
    tbd.commit()

    table_id = tbdcursor.execute('SELECT table_id FROM Tables').fetchall()
    global user_id_reservation
    user_id_reservation = tbdcursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM Tables').fetchall()
    user_id = cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM Users').fetchall()
    user_id_reservation = str(user_id_reservation).replace("(" , "")
    user_id_reservation = str(user_id_reservation).replace(")" , "")
    user_id_reservation = str(user_id_reservation).replace("," , "")

    if [item for item in user_id if message.chat.id in item] :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'✅Вы есть в нашей базе данных!')
        update_info(message.chat.id)
    else : 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'✅Вы добавлены в нашу базу данных!')
        db_add(message.chat.id , message.from_user.first_name)
        update_info(message.chat.id)

    if str(message.chat.id) in user_id_reservation : 
        table_id_selected = tbdcursor.execute('SELECT table_id FROM Tables WHERE user_id = ?', (message.chat.id,)).fetchone()
        table_id_selected = str(table_id_selected).replace("(" , "")
        table_id_selected = str(table_id_selected).replace(")" , "")
        table_id_selected = str(table_id_selected).replace("," , "")
        update_table_info(table_id_selected)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'Здравствуйте , {message.from_user.first_name} Вас приветствует NehaBarKST , у вас забронирован столик пол номером {tables[0]}')
        buffer_table = 1
    else :
        buffer_table = 0
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'Здравствуйте , {message.from_user.first_name} Вас приветствует NehaBarKST')

    if user[2] == 1 :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , "Пожалуйста выберите действие:" , reply_markup=admin_markup)
    else : bot.send_message(message.chat.id , "Пожалуйста выберите действие:" , reply_markup=markup)

jls_extract_var = bot
@jls_extract_var.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True) 

def answer(call) :
    global check
    global buffer_table
    tabledbconnect()
    table_id = tbdcursor.execute('SELECT table_id FROM Tables').fetchall()
    user_id_reservation = tbdcursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM Tables').fetchall()
    user_id = cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM Users').fetchall()
    user_id_reservation = str(user_id_reservation).replace("(" , "")
    user_id_reservation = str(user_id_reservation).replace(")" , "")
    user_id_reservation = str(user_id_reservation).replace("," , "")

    if call.data == "table" :
        pattern = r'^\+?[0-9]{11,12}$'
        match = re.search(pattern, user[3])
        if match :
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
            if str(call.message.chat.id) in user_id_reservation :
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'Вы уже забронировали стол! \nПроверьте бронь в профиле' , reply_markup=markup)
            else :
                global table_markup
                table_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)
                for item in table_id :
                    item = str(item).replace("(" , "")
                    item = str(item).replace(")" , "")
                    item = str(item).replace("," , "")
                    update_table_info(int(item))
                    if tables[1] == 1 : None
                    else : table_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'{item} стол (от {tables[7]} до {tables[8]} человек)' , callback_data = str(item)))
                with open(table_image_path, 'rb') as table_img:
                    bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id , table_img , caption='️Выберите стол' , reply_markup=table_markup)
        else : 
            bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , 'Пожалуйста укажите корректный номер телефона для связи с вами') , add_phone_num)

    for item in table_id :
        item = str(item).replace("(" , "")
        item = str(item).replace(")" , "")
        item = str(item).replace("," , "")
        if call.data == "" + str(item) :
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
            global table_reserv
            table_reserv = int(item)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , '️Укажите дату и время для бронирования формате ДД.ММ ЧЧ:ММ \n1-31.1-12 21:00-4:00 \nПример : 21.07 21:30'), table_reservation)

    if call.data == "help" :
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , "Инстарграм бара : instagram.com/nehabar_kst \nСвязь с администрацией : \n⚠️Сообщить об ошибке : @CaH4eZOV" , reply_markup=markup)

    elif call.data == "profile" :
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        update_info(call.message.chat.id)

        global profile_markup
        profile_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        update_name = types.InlineKeyboardButton("✏️Обновить имя" , callback_data='update_name')
        add_phone_number = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Добавить номер телефона" , callback_data='add_phone')
        delete_reservation = types.InlineKeyboardButton("️Удалить бронь" , callback_data='delete_reservation')
        back = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Назад" , callback_data='back')

        profile_markup.add(update_name,add_phone_number ,delete_reservation ,back)

        if buffer_table == 1 :
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'‍Профиль \n{user[1]}\nВаш персональный ID {user[0]} \nНомер телефона {user[3]} \n️Номер стола {tables[0]} \n️Время и дата {tables[5]} \n‍♂️Количество персон {tables[6]}' , reply_markup=profile_markup)
        else : bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'‍Профиль \n{user[1]}\nВаш персональный ID {user[0]} \nНомер телефона {user[3]}' , reply_markup=profile_markup)
    elif call.data == 'add_phone' :
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , 'Пожалуйста напишите номер телефона') , update_phon_number)

    elif call.data == "update_name" :
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        cursor.execute('UPDATE Users SET username = ? WHERE user_id = ?' , (call.from_user.first_name , call.message.chat.id))
        db.commit()
        update_info(call.message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'‍Профиль \n{user[1]}\nВаш персональный ID {user[0]} \nНомер телефона {user[3]}' , reply_markup=profile_markup)

    elif call.data == "delete_reservation" :
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        if buffer_table == 1 :
            tbdcursor.execute('UPDATE Tables SET reservation = ? , user_id = ? , name = ? , time = ? , phone_number = ? , persons = ? WHERE table_id = ?' , (0 , 0 , "" , 0 , 0 , 0 , tables[0]))
            tbd.commit()
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'‍Профиль \n{user[1]}\nВаш персональный ID {user[0]} \nНомер телефона {user[3]} \n' , reply_markup=profile_markup)
            buffer_table = 0
            admin_send_not_reservation()
        else : bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'❌У вас нет броней!' , reply_markup=profile_markup)
    elif call.data == "back" :
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , "Пожалуйста выберите действие:" , reply_markup=markup)

    elif call.data == "admin_update_tables_photo" :
        bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , '️Отправьте новое изображение плана столов') , admin_update_tables_photo)

    elif call.data == "admin_check_reserv" :
        check = 0
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        for item in table_id :
            item = str(item).replace("(" , "")
            item = str(item).replace(")" , "")
            item = str(item).replace("," , "")
            update_table_info(int(item))
            if tables[1] == 1 : 
                check = 1
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f' : {tables[3]} \nID : {tables[4]} \n️Номер стола : {tables[0]} \n️Дата и время : {tables[5]} \nНомер телефона : {tables[2]} \n‍♂️Количество человек : {tables[6]}')
            else :
                None
        if check != 1 : bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'❌Броней нет' , reply_markup=admin_markup) 
        else : bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'Пожалуйста выберите действие:' , reply_markup=admin_markup)    

    elif call.data == "admin_del_reserv" :
        check = 0
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        admin_del_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for item in table_id :
            item = str(item).replace("(" , "")
            item = str(item).replace(")" , "")
            item = str(item).replace("," , "")
            update_table_info(int(item))
            if tables[1] == 1 : 
                check = 1
                admin_del_markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'️{item} стол ({tables[6]} человек | дата и время {tables[5]})' , callback_data = str(item)+"admin")) 
            else :
                None
        admin_del_markup.add(admin_back)
        if check != 1 : bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'❌Броней нет' , reply_markup=admin_markup) 
        else : bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , "Выберите бронь для удаления" , reply_markup=admin_del_markup)

    for item in table_id :
        item = str(item).replace("(" , "")
        item = str(item).replace(")" , "")
        item = str(item).replace("," , "")            
        if call.data == "" + str(item)+"admin" :
            admin_delete_reservation(item)  
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message.id)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'✅Бронь успешно удалена!' , reply_markup=admin_markup)    

    if call.data == "admin_back" :
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id , call.message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , "Пожалуйста выберите действие:" , reply_markup=admin_markup)

    elif call.data == "admin_edit_spam" :
        bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'Напишите текст для рассылки'), admin_edit_spam_text)

    if call.data == "admin_start_spam" :
        bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id , f'Подтвердите действие в текстовом виде\n(Да/Нет)'), admin_start_spam)

def add_phone_num(message) :
    pattern = r'^\+?[0-9]{11,12}$'
    match = re.search(pattern, message.text)
    if match:
        cursor.execute('UPDATE Users SET phone_number = ? WHERE user_id = ?' , (message.text , message.chat.id))
        db.commit()
        update_info(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'✅Номер телефона успешно добавлен!' , reply_markup=markup)
    else : 
        bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'Введите корректный номер телефона! \nВ формате : +77772126548'), add_phone_num)

def table_reservation(message) :
    pattern = r'(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]).(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]) (?:21:[0-5][0-9]|22:[0-5][0-9]|23:[0-5][0-9]|00:[0-5][0-9]|01:[0-5][0-9]|02:[0-5][0-9]|03:[0-5][0-9])'
    match = re.search(pattern, message.text)
    if match:
        reservation_info = match.group(0)
        tbdcursor.execute('UPDATE Tables SET reservation = ? , user_id = ? , name = ? , time = ? , phone_number = ? WHERE table_id = ?' , (1 , message.chat.id , user[1] , message.text , user[3] , table_reserv))
        update_table_info(table_reserv)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(message.chat.id , '‍♂️Укажите количество персон') , table_reservation_persons)
    else :
        bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'⚠️Пожалуйста , введите дату и время в верном формате ДД.ММ ЧЧ:ММ \n1-31.1-12 20:00-04:00') , table_reservation)

def table_reservation_persons(message):
    if int(message.text) < tables[7] or int(message.text) > tables[8]:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'⚠️Недопустимое количество персон!', reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        try:
            tbd.execute('COMMIT')
            tbd.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
            tbd.execute('UPDATE Tables SET persons = ? WHERE table_id = ?', (message.text, table_reserv))
            tbd.commit()
            update_table_info(table_reserv)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'✅Вы успешно забронировали стол!', reply_markup=markup)
            buffer_table = 1
            admin_send_reservation()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            tbd.rollback()
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'❌Произошла ошибка при бронировании: {e}', reply_markup=markup)


def update_phon_number(message) :
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id , message.message_id-1)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id , message.message_id)
    pattern = r'^\+?[0-9]{11,12}$'
    match = re.search(pattern, message.text)
    if match:
        cursor.execute('UPDATE Users SET phone_number = ? WHERE user_id = ?' , (message.text , message.chat.id))
        db.commit()
        update_info(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'‍Профиль \n{user[1]}\nВаш персональный ID {user[0]} \nНомер телефона {user[3]}' , reply_markup=profile_markup)
    else : bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'⚠️Введите корректный номер телефона! \nВ формате : +77772126548'), update_phon_number)

def admin_send_reservation() :
    bot.send_message(admin_id, f'✅НОВАЯ БРОНЬ! НОВАЯ БРОНЬ!✅ \nИмя : {tables[3]} \nID : {tables[4]} \n️Номер стола : {tables[0]} \n️Дата и время : {tables[5]} \nНомер телефона : {tables[2]} \n‍♂️Количество человек : {tables[6]}')

def admin_send_not_reservation() :
    bot.send_message(admin_id, f'❌ОТМЕНА БРОНИ! ОТМЕНА БРОНИ!❌ \nИмя : {tables[3]} \nID : {tables[4]} \n️Номер стола : {tables[0]} \n️Дата и время : {tables[5]} \nНомер телефона : {tables[2]} \n‍♂️Количество человек : {tables[6]}')

def admin_delete_reservation(admin_table_id) :
    tbdcursor.execute('UPDATE Tables SET reservation = ? , user_id = ? , name = ? , time = ? , phone_number = ? , persons = ? WHERE table_id = ?' , (0 , 0 , "" , 0 , 0 , 0 , admin_table_id))
    tbd.commit()    
    update_table_info(admin_table_id)

def admin_update_tables_photo(message) :
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    file_info = bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file_info.file_path
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_path)
    with open('tables_photo.jpg', 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "✅Картинка успешно загружена!" , reply_markup=admin_markup)

def admin_edit_spam_text(message) :
    file_name = "spam_text.txt"
    with open(file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(message.text)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'️Загрузите фотографию'), admin_photo_edit_spam)

def admin_photo_edit_spam(message) :
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    file_info = bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file_info.file_path
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_path)
    with open('spam_photo.jpg', 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "✅Рассылка настроенна!" , reply_markup=admin_markup)

def admin_start_spam(message) :
    global text_spam
    if message.text == "Да" :  
        file_name = "spam_text.txt"
        with open(file_name, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            text_spam = file.read()
        dbconnect()
        users_id = cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM Users').fetchall()
        for item in users_id :
            item = str(item).replace("(" , "")
            item = str(item).replace(")" , "")
            item = str(item).replace("," , "")
            with open(spam_image_path, 'rb') as spam_img :  
                bot.send_photo(int(item) , spam_img , caption=""+text_spam)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'✅Расыслка запущена!')
    elif message.text == "Нет" :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id , f'❌Рассылка не запущена!')

bot.infinity_polling()


https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
